# How do I run my iOS app (Xcode 6) with the aps-environment set to "production"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

I'm developing an app with Xcode 6 and I want to test production push notifications but I can't seem to run my app with a production aps-environment. How can I manually enable this for testing purposes?

I've already registered my app through **Apple Developer** with both development and production push notification certificates and everything works fine using the sand-box developer push notification environment. But I'm having problems registering for production push tokens and keep receiving development push tokens instead.

I tried changing the code signing identity of the target to **iOS Distribution** but that led to other problems and I couldn't even launch my app. Can I only use a production aps-environment after the app has been released? If so then how do I test production push notifications before release?

Further information is that the app still hasn't been released yet and I'm using Amazon SNS on a node.js server for delivering pushes. Once again, the whole chain is working perfectly using the APNS_Sandbox (developer) environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use production APS, your app has to be signed with a production provisioning profile.

Try this:

1. Create an Ad Hoc provisioning profile with your phone's device identifier included in it.
2. Set your Release target's provisioning profile to this new provisioning profile.
3. Archive your app (Product > Archive in Xcode). Note: make sure that Archive builds the release target.
4. Export the .ipa of your app (Export > Save for Ad Hoc deployment in Organizer) and install that on your phone (drag it into iTunes, on your device in the Devices organizer, etc).

When you run that version, your app should be sending the production tokens. To my knowledge, you're not able to directly put production versions of your app onto your phone through Xcode (but I may be wrong).

Comment: Thanks this worked! Sucks that there isn't a more elegant way around this though. I don't understand why we have to manage two completely independent push systems (dev and prod), and that it's such a hassle to test production infrastructure.

Comment: A side question Aaron, is there a way or variable to know if you're using a production or development provisioning profile from within the app?

Comment: You could check if "DEBUG" is defined. It's an environment variable that's set in the default debug configuration but not the default release configuration.

Comment: how do I then debug this ad hoc .ipa?